# Append new content at the end of page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hello   cant help myself.  i have a page where the users can post there status.  but i wnat that the new posts appear at the end of the page (bottom)  after the older posts, when the user press the button.

at the moment ajax sets all new posts at the top of the older posts.
i want reverse.

i have this snippet here inside a function and i know its just a bit to change in this piece but i couldn't figure out which way to change.

```
var currentHTML = _("statusdescrib").innerHTML;
var currentdbxHTML = _("databox").innerHTML;
        _("statusdescrib").innerHTML = '<div id="status_'+sid+'" class="status_boxes"><div>Posted by you just now:<span id="sdb_'+sid+'"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deleteStatus(\''+sid+'\',\'status_'+sid+'\');" title="DELETE THIS STATUS">delete</a></span></div></div>'+currentHTML;
            _("databox").innerHTML = '<div id="status_'+sid+'" class="status_boxes">'+data+'</div>'+currentdbxHTML;
```

thanks for any help

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put currentHTML before your newly inserted html, like this:

```
var currentdbxHTML = _("databox").innerHTML;
        _("statusdescrib").innerHTML = currentHTML+'<div id="status_'+sid+'" class="status_boxes"><div>Posted by you just now:<span id="sdb_'+sid+'"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deleteStatus(\''+sid+'\',\'status_'+sid+'\');" title="DELETE THIS STATUS">delete</a></span></div></div>';
            _("databox").innerHTML = '<div id="status_'+sid+'" class="status_boxes">'+data+'</div>'+currentdbxHTML;
```

As you can see in the second line I moved the +currenHTML in front of the HTML snippet that get's included to read currentHTML+...

Comment: yepp i tried this before and it didnt worked  but now i tried again after your suggestion  and its worked fine.  thank you   and thx for the quick reply. your great

Comment: It's karma, sometimes when you get help from others it magically works ;) I also do helpdesk work and sometimes customers get stuff to work right when you pick up the phone. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: do you also know why its shows nothing in a complete new status site ?? when its the first post  and no content before then its wont appear now??

Comment: hehe yeppp karma is everywhere   goood luck for you too.  thanks